# Check for file extension or mime type fails

Tags: csv, file-upload, wordpress

I need to check if a uploaded file has `.csv` or `.txt` as extension and I'm doing as follow:

```
$uploadfiles = $_FILES['uploadfiles'];

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($uploadfiles);
echo '</pre>';

if (is_array($uploadfiles)) {
    foreach ($uploadfiles['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($uploadfiles['error'][$key] == 0) {

            $filetmp = $uploadfiles['tmp_name'][$key];
            $filename = $uploadfiles['name'][$key];

            $filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null);
            $filetitle = preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename));
            $filename = $filetitle . '.' . $filetype['ext'];
            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

            if ($uploadfiles['type'] != "text/csv" || $uploadfiles['type'] != "text/plain") {
                echo "Error, the file $filename has not a valid extension: " . $filetype["ext"];
                continue;
            }

            echo "entre";die();

            $i = 0;
            while (file_exists($upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename)) {
                $filename = $filetitle . '_' . $i . '.' . $filetype['ext'];
                $i++;
            }

            $filedest = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;

            if (!is_writeable($upload_dir['path'])) {
                $this->msg_e('Unable to write to directory %s. Is this directory writable by the server?');
                return;
            }

            if (!move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filedest)) {
                $this->msg_e("Error, the file $filetmp could not moved to : $filedest ");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error all the time:

> Error, the file Aruba Airlines tickets-coupons (through 27-Apr-2014) -
>   Aruba Airlines tickets-coupons .csv has not a valid extension: csv

I also test with this code:

```
if ($filetype['type'] != "text/csv" || $filetype['type'] != "text/plain") {
    echo "Error, the file $filename has not a valid extension: " . $filetype["ext"];
    continue;
}
```

And result is the same. If I do this:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($uploadfiles);
echo '</pre>';
```

I get this as result:

```
array (size=5)
  'name' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Aruba Airlines tickets-coupons (through 27-Apr-2014) - Aruba Airlines tickets-coupons .csv' (length=90)
  'type' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'text/csv' (length=8)
  'tmp_name' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '/tmp/php53tzhZ' (length=14)
  'error' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 0
  'size' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 14084526
```

So where is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you've already asked your question at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149093/check-for-file-extension-or-mime-type-fails/). But here's an answer so that question doesn't remain unanswered.

### Check Filetype

Retrieve the file type from the file name.

You can optionally define the mime array, if needed.

```
<?php wp_check_filetype( $filename, $mimes ) ?>
```

### Check Filetype & Extension

Attempts to determine the real file type of a file.

If unable to, the file name extension will be used to determine type. If it's determined that the extension does not match the file's real type, then the "proper_filename" value will be set with a proper filename and extension.

```
 <?php
      $validate = wp_check_filetype_and_ext( $file, $filename, $mimes );

      if( $validate['proper_filename'] !== false )
          $filename = $validate['proper_filename'];
 ?>
```

Reference:

> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_filetype
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_filetype_and_ext